# How to download MPEG Dash (mpd file) using youtube-dl when headers are requested and getting HTTP Error 403

Tags: stream, youtube-dl, request-headers

I've used Chrome developer tools to [inspect network activity](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network) and filter the mpd file.
I've get the URL of the mpd with the context menu copy link address.
But when I've assembled the youtube-dl command line it get HTTP Error 403: Forbidden.

So I've tried to add the --verbose option to get more information and found a warning "Could not send HEAD request" so I've assumed I needed to send also the headers.
I can get the headers with the context menu copy as cURL in the mpd file listed in network activity inspector.

Downloading with curl works for the manifest, but how can I provide headers to youtube-dl to send them properly?

Answer (score 10):

The cURL copy from Chrome developer tools filtered entry in the inspect network activity will provide this kind of string:

```
curl 'https://source-of-video.net/folder/manifest.mpd' \
  -H 'authority: source-of-video.net' \
  -H 'pragma: no-cache' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'dnt: 1' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'origin: https://origin-website-of-video' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: cross-site' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'referer: https://origin-website-of-video/origin.html' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8,it;q=0.7,pt;q=0.6' \
  --compressed
```

Just replacing `-H` with `--add-header` and `curl` with `youtube-dl` and deleting `--compressed` will do the trick, ending up like this (headers are only examples):

```
youtube-dl 'https://source-of-video.net/folder/manifest.mpd' \
  --add-header 'authority: source-of-video.net' \
  --add-header 'pragma: no-cache' \
  --add-header 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  --add-header 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36' \
  --add-header 'dnt: 1' \
  --add-header 'accept: */*' \
  --add-header 'origin: https://origin-website-of-video' \
  --add-header 'sec-fetch-site: cross-site' \
  --add-header 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  --add-header 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  --add-header 'referer: https://origin-website-of-video/origin.html' \
  --add-header 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8,it;q=0.7,pt;q=0.6' \
```

Comment: How can you add these headers in windows?

Comment: It should work, likely if you have issues is related to the character required to escape other special characters and issue multi-line commands, in windows if you are using cmd it is the caret instead of the backslash. HTH

Comment: Just to avoid possibile bother, we could add `--no-check-certificate`